# How to position (shift) Oracle Apex 4.2 form left and right?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3yxb.jpg)[image: Here's the application interface and a part of the form is behind the side dashboard of my template]

Here's the application interface and a part of the form is behind the side dashboard of my template

```html
           
<section class="uRegion #REGION_CSS_CLASSES# clearfix" id="#REGION_STATIC_ID#" #REGION_ATTRIBUTES#>
  <div class="uRegionHeading">
    <h1>#TITLE#</h1>
    <span class="uButtonContainer">
      #CLOSE##PREVIOUS##NEXT##DELETE##EDIT##CHANGE##CREATE##CREATE2##EXPAND##COPY##HELP#
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="uRegionContent clearfix">
    width: 1360px;
    height: 1002px;
    right: 500px;
    #BODY#
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not an X-Y problem? Your dashboard is obscuring part of your form; instead of fixing that issue, you're proposing to move the dashboard to the right-side of the form. However, that might then cause the dashboard to obscure your "Cancel" and "Create" buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to theme 42. It is possible that you're using a custom theme.

Comment: I'm using apex 4.2, its theme 26 and i used my own template, all i need is to just shift the form to the right, i figured out how to control its width and height, just need to shift it to the right

Comment: If you're using your own template, you need to fix your template. Without seeing your code there's not much we can do for you.

Comment: The problem isn't in my template, the form gets behind it, and i thought if i could control its width and height, then i can control its position

Comment: The problem isn't in my template, its in the form region, i thought if i could control its width and height by the region attribute ( style = " width:650px;height:700px;" ) then i can control its position, i just don't know the instructions for that